# how to set my array in react from a service call

Tags: reactjs

I have an array and I am making a service call and I would like to set all the returned json array to my react array here is the code so far:

```
interface QuestionHeader {
  id: number;
  questionName: string;
  Question: Question;
}

const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionHeader[]>([]);
  function runService() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    fetch(`URL`, requestOptions)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => {
      setQuestions()

    });
  }
```

Here is the JSON:
{
"id": 2,
"questionID": 2,
"questionName": "Customer Satisfaction",
"question": [
{
"questionID": 2,
"questionContent": "brand satisfaction"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionHeader[]>([]);
  function runService() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    fetch("URL", requestOptions)
    .then(res => setQuestions(res.json()))
  }
```